Trouble Identifying Inbuilt Webcam on Dell Precision 5480 Running Ubuntu
I recently acquired a new Dell Precision 5480 laptop, and I'm encountering difficulties identifying the inbuilt webcam. Whenever I attempt to access camera services, I receive a "NO Device Found" message.
I'm seeking assistance to resolve this issue. If anyone has experience or suggestions regarding how to troubleshoot and rectify this problem, I would greatly appreciate your guidance.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Follow the instructions at https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000203830/webcam-is-not-detected-on-xps-13-plus-9320-laptops-running-ubuntu-22-04.
Note that after doing this you will have to go into Software & Updates, choose the camera driver and apply changes. After this, you should run Software Updates and then reboot your PC.

I have the same laptop (Dell precision 5480) and was able to get it working.
